# jQuery Datatables: Custom copy-to-clipboard function

Tags: datatables

The built-in copy-to-clipboard function in Datatables can copy the table head with the selected rows, so it pastes like this (Title, Number and Comment being columns):

```
Title Number Comment
Test   102    "nice"
Test2  103   "ok"
```

I need it like this:

```
Title: Test Number: 102 Comment: "nice"
Title: Test2 Number: 103 Comment: "ok"
```

My Datatables setup for the copy-button is currently like this:

```
dom: 'Bfrtip',
buttons: {
       buttons: [
         {
            extend: 'copyHtml5',
            text: 'Copy Selected Rows',
            header: false,
            exportOptions: {
                 modifier: {
                        selected: true
                 }
            }
         }
       ]
}
```

Is there a function to archive this? Or how can I modify the copying process?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **SOLUTION**

You can use [`orthogonal`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/buttons.exportData%28%29) option to specify data type `copy` requested for copy operations and [`columns.render`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) to render appropriate content when data type `copy` is requested.

```
$('#example').DataTable({
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    columnDefs: [{
        targets: "_all",
        render: function (data, type, full, meta) {
            if (type === 'copy') {
                var api = new $.fn.dataTable.Api(meta.settings);

                data = $(api.column(meta.col).header()).text() + ": " + data;
            }

            return data;
        }
    }],
    buttons: [{
        extend: 'copyHtml5',
        text: 'Copy Selected Rows',
        header: false,
        exportOptions: {
            modifier: {
                selected: true
            },
            orthogonal: 'copy'
        }
    }]
});
```

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gub6zdho/1/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: Thank you, sir! You're truly a Datatables genius.